# UIWebview: Dynamically adding html content

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview

I am making an app in which I get text from my server and display it in UIWebview. After some time more text is added and client(iphone) is notified about the additional-text. Now I want to inject this text into my UIWebview.

One method is to update some text file and reload the content. `But I dont want to reload the page.`

Another way can be to use javascript to check updates in a local file (which seems better).

Is there any known better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting the data from the server, why not just use `JavaScript` and preform an [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request to update the page?

This allows you to skip the middle man of updating the 'template' file. Just load all of your data with [`AJAX`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in order to always have the most 'up-to date' data on the page.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajax/test.html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
    alert('Load was performed.');
  }
});
```

Comment: this data is based on twitter and facebook authentication which I get from native iphone APIs. So I have to use these authentications to get the data from twitter and facebook.. and plus some of my custom data

Answer (score 1):

I believe javascript is better if you want to keep all user edited data (if there is some).
And also should be faster than reloading all page.